# React Router: No Match on dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, react-router

It's been a while since I've used react route and would like to ask for help when it comes to an invalid match on a dynamic routing

say this is my code:

```
<Switch> 
<Route exact path="/"  component={Home} />
<Route exact path="/games/:games"  component={Content} />
<Route component={Notfound} />
</Switch>
```

I have a Notfound component so that any invalid URL from the root level would be captured and be redirected to my homepage (e.g. [www.domain.com/invalid](http://www.domain.com/invalid)).

My problem is redirecting any invalid dynamic route. Say, [www.domain.com/games/invalidgameid666](http://www.domain.com/games/invalidgameid666) where invalidgameid666 does not have any match on my gameIds.
Can anyone please shed some light on how to do a redirect in this case?

Comment: The `Content` component needs to check for the validity and redirect to home when appropriate.

Comment: Thank you! just wanted to check if there's an easier way of doing this before spending time creating validation on content.